# Systematic way to show equality between ideals of $K[x,y]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, primary-decomposition

I am studying primary decompositions.

> I am struggling to show that $$I = \left<xy, x^3-x^2, x^2y-xy\right> = \left<x\right>\cap \left<x-1,y\right> \cap \left<x^2,y\right>$$ where $I$ is an ideal of $K[x,y]$.

I tried get an generic element $f$ in $\left<x\right>\cap \left<x-1,y\right> \cap \left<x^2,y\right>$ and show that $f$ is in $I$, but I got lost in so many possibilities.

How can I show this equality?

Thanks

Comment: First notice that the third generator $x^2y-xy$ is superflous.

Comment: Anyway, notice that $(x)\cap(x^2,y)=(x^2,xy)$, and write $f=x^2g+xyh$. Since $f\in (x-1,y)$ we have $x^2g\in(x-1,y)$. Now use that $(x-1,y)$ is prime and get $g\in(x-1,y)$, done.

Comment: I have this decomposition, I got stuck in the equality step. And yes, R is a field, sorry. I understood your answer, thank you

Comment: What I wanted to say is that the main bulk in such questions is to find out a primary decomposition. When it is given we can prove it somehow.